# What are the consequences of destroying the USS Constitution?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm on a mission from the navigator of the USS Constitution to get a guidance chip back from some scavengers that stole it, however upon speaking to the scavengers they've presented me with the opportunity to instead attack the USS Constitution and then loot it for scrap, or at least use me to attack the USS Constitution and then turn on me so I have to kill them all...

What are the consequences of attacking the USS Constitution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The biggest direct impact to your character is that you will miss out on being rewarded with the **Broadsider** *(A powerful weapon that fires cannonballs. Rewarded to you if you side with Ironsides.)*

From a story standpoint, if you side with the scavengers Davies will sabotage the rockets so that the ship will explode. After the rockets explode the ship will remain landlocked and the robot crew will turn hostile. You will then have to storm the boat with the scavengers and defeat Ironsides. Regardless of what dialogue option you choose the scavengers must be defeated to complete the quest.

Comment: So you still have to kill off the scavengers regardless? I knew they could not be trusted!

Comment: Yeah unfortunately they decide they will kill you either way, bad decision on their part :P

Answer (score -1):

Kill the scavangers they do nothing to benifit you in this quest. Plus who doesnt want to collect all the dope fallout weapons? This one rewards with the broadsider! Its a giant cannon! You can find cannon balls at the castle (follow the minutemen quest line to find the castle) and i believe one or two other locations.

Comment: This adds nothing that wasn't said several months ago.